# Ask for ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION using the ActivityResultLauncher

Tags: android, android-permissions, onactivityresult

Previously I was doing this by the standard 'startActivityForResult()' approach, catching the result in onActivityResult() callback. And it worked. But now the method has a big-strike though since it is deprecated so I am trying to use the new launcher approach. However, I always get the same result regardless of what the user does. result.getResultCode() always returns a failure. Double checking with Settings.canDrawOverlays(context) also returns failure even when the permission has been granted. Though far later in the code when I check using Settings.canDrawOverlays(context) it returns success. Putting in a delay in the launcher callback does not solve the inconsistency.

Here is my Launcher registration and callback:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultOverlayLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result)
                {
                    if (result.getResultCode() != Activity.RESULT_OK)
                    {
                        HaHStatics.debugLog(TAG, context, "d", "HH2: Permission for device discovery popups not given");
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Overlay Permission not given.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        // Double checking with Settings.canDrawOverlays(context) also always returns failure
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        HaHStatics.debugLog(TAG, context, "d", "HH2: Permission for device discovery popups given.");
                    }
                    // Do next thing
                }
            });
```

And here is the request code:

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void getSystemWindowAlertPermission()
    {
        HaHStatics.debugLog(TAG, context, "d", "HH2: Checking for permission to allow Alert popups");
        if (isVersionM_Plus && !Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) // isVersionM_Plus checks build >= OS 6
        {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            try
            {
                activityResultOverlayLauncher.launch(intent);
            }
            catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

The call to initiate the settings activity works fine in all versions of Android though version 11 requires a two-step navigation by the user.

The only thing I can think of is that I am using the wrong contract OR that the system is messing up and not setting what it needs to set until I return from the launcher callback.

I am at a loss.  Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

PS: this approach works great for asking all the Bluetooth and Location and background permissions needed to do discovery, scanning, and auto reconnects from versions OS 6  to 12.

Comment: "result.getResultCode() always returns a failure" -- `ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION` is [not documented to return a result](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION). So, this is the expected behavior. "Double checking with Settings.canDrawOverlays(context) also always returns failure" -- that is a bit surprising, but since this is not a standard runtime permission, I suppose that I really do not know what to expect.

Comment: @CommonsWare interesting - but when I use the deprecated startActivityForResult and use the onActivityResult() callback, it works. The Settings.canDrawOverlays(context) returns success. That is what is confusing me. I can get the user response using the old approach but not the new.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think it might be a bug on my Moto E5 Play version OS 8.0.0 device.  All my other phones I have tried respond correctly to the Settings.canDrawOverlays() even in the launcher response. The permission, is, nevertheless, set correctly by the phone so it must be that this phone does not update the settings until after I return from the callback. Turns out this phone responds incorrectly even using the old startActivityForResult approach.